# PlatformNotSupportedException thrown in Blazor Webassembly with Azure IoT Hub

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, azure-iot-hub

I am exploring `Blazor Webassembly`. I am porting a WPF application to evaluate the functionalities. The application is connecting to an `Azure IoT Hub` instance.

Here is the section of code that seems problematic:

```
var iotHubConnectionStringBuilder = IotHubConnectionStringBuilder.Create("HostName=<iotHubConnectionString>");

var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionStringBuilder.ToString());
```

When calling `CreateFromConnectionString`, the following exception is thrown:

```
Unhandled Exception:
       System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
          at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.get_SslOptions()
          at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpClientHelper.CreateDefaultHttpMessageHandler(IWebProxy webProxy, Uri baseUri, Int32 connectionLeaseTimeoutMilliseconds)
          at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpClientHelper.CreateDefaultClient(IWebProxy webProxy, Uri baseUri, Int32 connectionLeaseTimeoutMilliseconds)
          at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpClientHelper..ctor(Uri baseAddress, IAuthorizationHeaderProvider authenticationHeaderProvider, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 defaultErrorMapping, TimeSpan timeout, IWebProxy customHttpProxy, Int32 connectionLeaseTimeoutMilliseconds)
          at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.RegistryManager..ctor(IotHubConnectionProperties connectionProperties, HttpTransportSettings transportSettings)
          at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(String connectionString, HttpTransportSettings transportSettings)
          at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(String connectionString)
```

**Question**

Why is this error thrown and how can it be fixed?

**Update**

Surprisingly, I [encounter a similar issue in the MAUI version of the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72417944/platformnotsupportedexception-thrown-in-maui-on-macos-when-connecting-azure-iot) as well.

Comment: Exactly the same error in Maui? That seems strange.

Comment: Azure's CreateDefaultHttpMessageHandler is not comaptible with the Browser platform. There are no Sockets in Wasm.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Does that mean that the only workaround to this would be to move to Blazor Server instead of Webassembly so that this portion runs on the server which would not have this limitation? Is that a correct statement?

Comment: Blazor Server is one option, using an API server (Blazor Wasm Hosted) would work as well.