# PlatformNotSupportedException thrown in MAUI on macOS when connecting Azure IoT Hub

Tags: c#, .net, azure-iot-hub, maui, .net-maui

I am exploring `MAUI` on macOS. I am porting a WPF application to evaluate the functionalities. The application is connecting to an `Azure IoT Hub` instance.

Here is the section of code that seems problematic:

```
var iotHubConnectionStringBuilder = IotHubConnectionStringBuilder.Create("HostName=<iotHubConnectionString>");

var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionStringBuilder.ToString());
```

When calling `CreateFromConnectionString`, the following exception is thrown:

```
    Unhandled Exception:
           System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler.set_SslProtocols(SslProtocols value)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.InvokeNativeHandlerMethod(String name, Object[] parameters)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.SetSslProtocols(SslProtocols value)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_SslProtocols(SslProtocols value)
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.HttpClientHelper..ctor(Uri baseAddress, IAuthorizationProvider authenticationHeaderProvider, IDictionary`2 defaultErrorMapping, TimeSpan timeout, Action`1 preRequestActionForAllRequests, X509Certificate2 clientCert, HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler, ProductInfo productInfo, IWebProxy proxy, Boolean isClientPrimaryTransportHandler)
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.HttpTransportHandler..ctor(IPipelineContext context, IotHubConnectionString iotHubConnectionString, Http1TransportSettings transportSettings, HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler, Boolean isClientPrimaryTransportHandler)
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.InternalClient..ctor(IotHubConnectionString iotHubConnectionString, ITransportSettings[] transportSettings, IDeviceClientPipelineBuilder pipelineBuilder, ClientOptions options)
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.ClientFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(String connectionString, IAuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod, ITransportSettings[] transportSettings, IDeviceClientPipelineBuilder pipelineBuilder, ClientOptions options)
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.ClientFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(String connectionString, IAuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod, TransportType transportType, IDeviceClientPipelineBuilder pipelineBuilder, ClientOptions options)
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.ClientFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(String connectionString, TransportType transportType, ClientOptions options)
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.ClientFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(String connectionString, ClientOptions options)
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<CreateFromConnectionString>b__0()
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient.Create(Func`1 internalClientCreator)
at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(String connectionString, ClientOptions options)
[..]
```

I have played with the different `HttpClient` implementation without any positive outcome. And, surprinsingly enough, it exhibits the same callstack, with `NSUrlSessionHandler.set_SslProtocols` on top of it:

[image: HttpClient implementations]

**Question**

Why is this error thrown and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Have you googled `System.PlatformNotSupportedException set ssl protocols`?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I did and I did saw a couple of issues related to that specific exception. Some of them were related to .Net Framework, others related to libraries that got issues opened for them... but not related specifically to .net6 / MAUI / iOS - macos-catalyst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Visual Studio 2022 for Mac version 17.3 **Preview 1**. After updating to Visual Studio 2022 for Mac v17.3 **Preview 1.1** as well as the `.net MAUI` workload, it worked.

I let the `HttpClient` implementation to `NSUrlSession`.

I am not sure the exact reason *why* it works now but I assume these issues are bound to happen when using preview products.