# Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client ModuleClient change default HttpClientHandler

Tags: c#, azure, blazor-webassembly, azure-iot-hub

I would like to connect to the Azure Iot Hub module configuration.
The application is a .NET 7 Blazor WebAssembly.
When i run my code:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;

var deviceConnectionString = "HostName=test;SharedAccessKeyName=test;SharedAccessKey=test;deviceId=test;moduleId=test";
try
{
   var moduleClient = ModuleClient.CreateFromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString);
}
catch (PlatformNotSupportedException e)
{
   var exception = e;
   throw;
}
```

It's pretty much the same issue as in [PlatformNotSupportedException thrown in Blazor Webassembly with Azure IoT Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396173/platformnotsupportedexception-thrown-in-blazor-webassembly-with-azure-iot-hub), so what i get from there is that in Blazor WebAssembly the SocketsHttpHandler used by Azure is not supported.

But this answer unfortunately does not clarify how to work around the problem.

The issue says `Blazor Server is one option, using an API server (Blazor Wasm Hosted) would work as well.`
I'm not a blazor expert but i guess i am using a hosted blazor wasm - as i created a test project with `dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted` - and it does not work...

So is there maybe a way to tell Azure.Devices.Client that it should use `HttpClientHandler` instead of `SocketsHttpHandler`?
I guess then it should work?

Answer (score 0):

I could successfully connect to the Azure IoT Hub through Blazor Web App. For this to work, you would have to enable the option "ASP.NET Core Hosted" during the project creation. Refer the below image to check the option that is presented during the project creation in Visual Studio.

[image]

Once you have that option enabled, the connection works without throwing any errors. I have tested this on .Net frameworks 6 as well as 7. They both compiled and could connect to the Azure IoT Hub fine.

Here is the code I have used in my Server side Program.cs class to test the ModuleClient. I have also created a DeviceClient and passed a sample telemetry data to one of my devices to make sure I receive the data on to the IoT Hub.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

string deviceKey1 = "<DeviceKey>";
string deviceId1 = "<DeviceName>";
string iotHubHostName = "<HostName>";
Random Rand = new Random();
string[] channel = { "Channel", "Function" };
var deviceAuthentication1 = new 
DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(deviceId1, deviceKey1);
string deviceConnectionString = "HostName=HostName;DeviceId=DeviceName;ModuleId=ModuleName;SharedAccessKey=Key";
try
{
var moduleClient = ModuleClient.CreateFromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString);
DeviceClient deviceClient1 = DeviceClient.Create(iotHubHostName, deviceAuthentication1, TransportType.Mqtt);
double currentTemperature = 20 + Rand.NextDouble() * 15;
double currentHumidity = 60 + Rand.NextDouble() * 20;

var telemetryDataPoint1 = new
{
    messageId = 1,
    deviceId = deviceId1,
    source = channel[Rand.Next(0, 2)],
    temperature = currentTemperature,
    humidity = currentHumidity
};
string messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryDataPoint1);
Message message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));
message.ContentEncoding = "utf-8";
message.ContentType = "application/json";
message.Properties.Add("temperatureAlert", (currentTemperature > 30) ? "true" : "false");

await deviceClient1.SendEventAsync(message);
Console.WriteLine("{0} > Sending message: {1}", DateTime.Now, messageString);
}
catch (PlatformNotSupportedException e)
{
var exception = e;
throw;
}
```

As you can see from the below image, the telemetry data is pushed to the Azure cloud portal

[image]

Here is the loaded Blazor Web App after the successful code compilation

[image]